# Disable rewrite for a certain filename

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess redirect setup like this

```
Redirect / http://www.example.com
```

I need to allow a request to index-new.html to show that file and not do the redirection to example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with `Redirect`, but you might be able to use `mod_rewrite` and exclude that specific URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond !index-new\.html$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/
```